# Random Numbers and Variables in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, random-numbers, ifthenelse, random

Below is my MWE.
I understand the gist of tikz and foreachs, but when it comes to variables I don't understand most yet.

I want an arrow pointing from each cell to a module, and them from the module to the cluster output.

As you can see, I got the loop going, but I don't know how to get random numbers. I get *rand* to work, but that produces the output you can see below.

I thought about 2 ways:

1. Make an if statement to check what number the rand number is and link that to the modules.
   E.G rand == 1 -> Module 1; rand == 2 Module 2; rand == 3 Module 875 etc.
   I dont get it to work like `\ifnum\rand=1`
2. Get a random number from a set.

I'd prefer method 2, but if you can give me any tips on how to do either I'm glad!

Any help appreciated!

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            %   Papierformat A4
12pt,               %   Schrift 12-Punkt
headsepline,        %   mit Linie unter der Kopfzeile
numbers=noenddot,   %   Nummern ohne Punkt am Ende
bibliography=totoc, %   Literaturverzeichnis mit Nummer im 
Inhaltsverzeichnis (``TO Table Of Contents'')
index=totoc,        %   Index mit Nummer im Inhaltsverzeichnis
fleqn,              %   Formeln werden linksbündig statt zentriert 
angeordnet
headings=normal     %       Etwas kleinere Überschriften
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[first=1, last=4]{lcg}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}



\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!htb]

    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes = {minimum height=7mm, minimum width=1cm, anchor=center, draw, fill=white, inner sep=0, outer sep = 0},
    %column 1/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    %row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
    w/.style={fill=white},
    label=above:Digi Input] (Clusters) {
        &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[10cm]
    };

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (-6.5,-4) {Modul 1};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (-2.5,-4) {Modul 2};
    \node[ minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (0,-4) {$\cdots$};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (2.5,-4) {Modul 875};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (6.5,-4) {Modul 876};
    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{modules}{{-6.5}{-2.5}{2.5}{6.5}}
    %\foreach \x in {1,2,...,5}
    \newcounter{myrandom}{rand}
    \foreach \x in {-7.5, -6.5,..., 7.5}
        {   %\rand;
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\num}{modules}
            \draw [->, line width=0.5mm] (\x,-0.35) -- (\num,-2);}
    %\draw [fill=gray] (-8,-4) rectangle (-6,-1);
    %\draw [->, line width=0.5mm] (-7.5,-0.35) -- (-7,-0.95);
    %\node[font=\Huge\sffamily, draw] {Skippd};
    %\node[font=\Huge\sffamily, below left=0pt of Clusters-3-14.north east] {Skipped};



    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes = {minimum height=7mm, minimum width=1cm, anchor=center, draw, fill=white},
    %column 1/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    %row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
    w/.style={fill=white},
    label=below:Cluster Output] at (0,-8)(Cluster Output) {
        &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes = {minimum height=7mm, minimum width=1cm, anchor=center, draw, fill=white, inner sep=0, outer sep = 0},
    %column 1/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    %row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
    w/.style={fill=white},
    label=above:Digi Input] (Clusters) {
        &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[10cm]
    };

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (-6.5,-4) {Modul 1};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (-2.5,-4) {Modul 2};
    \node[ minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (0,-4) {$\cdots$};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (2.5,-4) {Modul 875};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (6.5,-4) {Modul 876};

    %\draw [->, line width=0.5mm] (-7.5,-0.35) -- (-6.5,-2);
    %\draw [fill=gray] (-8,-4) rectangle (-6,-1);
    %\draw [->, line width=0.5mm] (-7.5,-0.35) -- (-7,-0.95);
    %\node[font=\Huge\sffamily, draw] {Skippd};
    %\node[font=\Huge\sffamily, below left=0pt of Clusters-3-14.north east] {Skipped};



    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes = {minimum height=7mm, minimum width=1cm, anchor=center, draw, fill=white},
    %column 1/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    %row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
    w/.style={fill=white},
    label=below:Cluster Output] at (0,-8)(Cluster Output) {
        &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Lokale Rekonstruktion}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is the command `\pgfmathrandomitem` that allows you to get a random iterm from a list, see p. 1012 of the pgfmanual. But I am not sure what you want to achieve. Could you perhaps describe it a bit more?

Comment: Can you link me the manual? All manuals I have, have less than 1000 pages.
Edit: I found it elsewhere. Works like a charm! I updated my answer for you to see what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Do you maybe have any quick idea how to stop the arrows from overlapping so much? Escpecially where it points to, e.g. when the arrows go into the modules form the top side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pgf comes with a tool that selects a random item from a list. In your example, one can do, as you said

```
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{modules}{{1}{2}{3}{4}}
\pgfmathrandomitem{\num}{modules}
```

This is to summarize our conversation in the comments. As for your question: "Do you maybe have any quick idea how to stop the arrows from overlapping so much?": No, I do not have a magical tool that disentangles the arrows. What I can offer is something that makes the arrow color depend on the module and the angles of the incoming arrows arguably a bit nicer.

```
\documentclass[
a4paper,            %   Papierformat A4
12pt,               %   Schrift 12-Punkt
headsepline,        %   mit Linie unter der Kopfzeile
numbers=noenddot,   %   Nummern ohne Punkt am Ende
bibliography=totoc, %   Literaturverzeichnis mit Nummer im 
Inhaltsverzeichnis (``TO Table Of Contents'')
index=totoc,        %   Index mit Nummer im Inhaltsverzeichnis
fleqn,              %   Formeln werden linksbündig statt zentriert 
angeordnet
headings=normal     %       Etwas kleinere Überschriften
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes = {minimum height=7mm, minimum width=1cm, anchor=center, draw, fill=white, inner sep=0, outer sep = 0},
    %column 1/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    %row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
    w/.style={fill=white},
    label=above:Digi Input] (Clusters) {
        &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\[10cm]
    };

    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm]
     (module-1) at (-6.5,-4) {Modul 1};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] 
     (module-2) at (-2.5,-4) {Modul 2};
    \node[ minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] at (0,-4) {$\cdots$};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] 
     (module-3) at (2.5,-4) {Modul 875};
    \node[draw, shape=rectangle, minimum height=4cm,minimum width=3cm] 
     (module-4)at (6.5,-4) {Modul 876};



    \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes = {minimum height=7mm, minimum width=1cm, anchor=center, draw, fill=white},
    %column 1/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    %row 1/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 1 column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none, fill=none}},
    w/.style={fill=white},
    label=below:Cluster Output] at (0,-8)(Cluster Output) {
        &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
    };

    \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{modules}{{1}{2}{3}{4}}
    \edef\LstColors{"black","red","green!70!black","blue"}
    \foreach \Y in {1,...,16}
        {   %\rand;
            \pgfmathrandomitem{\num}{modules}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\num-1]}
            \path (Clusters-1-\Y.south) --  (module-\num.90-2*\Y+17)
            coordinate[pos=0.4] (aux0) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux1);
            \draw [-latex,thick,\mycolor] let \p1=($(aux1)-(aux0)$),
            \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
            (Clusters-1-\Y.south) to[out=-90,in=\n1+180]
            (aux0) -- (aux1) to[out=\n1,in=90]  (module-\num.90-4*\Y+34);}
%   
%   \foreach \X in {1,2,875,876}
%   {\foreach \Y in {1,...,16}
%   {\draw[-latex,thick] (Clusters-1-\Y.south) to (module-\X.north);
%   \draw[-latex,thick] (module-\X.south) to (Cluster Output-1-\Y.north);}}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Lokale Rekonstruktion}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you replace the loop by

```
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{modules}{{1}{2}{3}{4}}
\edef\LstColors{"black","red","green!70!black","blue"}
\foreach \Y in {1,...,16}
    {   %\rand;
        \pgfmathrandomitem{\num}{modules}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\LstColors}[\num-1]}
        \draw[thick,-latex,\mycolor] (Clusters-1-\Y.south) 
        to[out=-90,in=90,looseness=0.3]  (module-\num.90-4*\Y+34);}
```

you get

[image]

Comment: Mhm I thought i understood it, but do you mind explaining that part?
 `\path (Clusters-1-\Y.south) --  (module-\num.90-2*\Y+17)
   coordinate[pos=0.4] (aux0) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux1);
   \draw [-latex,thick,\mycolor] let \p1=($(aux1)-(aux0)$),
   \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)} in 
    (Clusters-1-\Y.south) to[out=-90,in=\n1+180]
    (aux0) -- (aux1) to[out=\n1,in=90]  (module-\num.90-4*\Y+34);`

Especially, what does coordinate[post=..] (aux0) and (aux1) do?

Comment: @Rhynden This works as follows: first, a line path between the input and the (random) module is constructed, and two (auxiliary) coordinates are recorded: `aux0` at 40% of the path and `aux1` at 60%. In the second part, the slope of this line is computed (`\n1`) and used to draw the arrow which starts out at an angle of -90 and then merges the line at the stretch from `aux0` to `aux1` where it has the slope of this line at the point it meets it and finally hits the module again at an angle of 90. I will also add an alternative.

Comment: Wow thanks, that's literally perfect and that explanation was superb! I was able to replicate and mess around, though I didn't get it to look nicer than that.
On a side note, looseness set to 1 looks almost like your solution before.
Anyways huge thanks!